# How to mark a directory as a generated-test-source root in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying out Dagger2 in Intellij 2016.1 (but not with gradle) on ubuntu.

Intellij creates dagger's generated sources in either
`./out/production/<ProjectModule>/generated/` or
`./out/test/<ProjectModule>/generated_tests/` depending on if it was generated from a source or test directory, respectively.

But from what I tell, I can only mark those directories as either `sources root`, `test sources root`, or `generated sources root`; there is no option for `generated test sources root`, say.

Why is this important? Because the generated test sources depend on *my* test sources. If they are marked as a `generated sources root` then Intellij cannot find the dependencies.

Note: I don't think they should be marked as `test sources root` because then Intellij tries to compile those again; unless there is some way of preventing this of which I am unaware.

So is there a way to mark this directory as a `generated test sources root` or something equivalent?

Answer (score 7):

To mark a diectory as "generated test sources root", open the "Project Structure" dialog at Project Settings > Modules and click on the little "P" next to your folder of choice, and select the "For generated resources" button.

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Dagger uses annotation processing to generate sources during compilation. IntelliJ has a specific configuration for this feature in [`Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-annotation-processing.html)
When it is enabled IntelliJ automatically adds generated sources to project.

With annotation processing enabled I can see that generated test sources are marked both as `Test Sources Root` and `Generated Sources Root`. But when I try to manually set both flags it does not work - I get flags `Sources Root` and `Generated Sources Root`.

For me it looks like a bug.

Comment: I have that option enabled and it produces generated sources as I mentioned in the question, but does not include them in the classpath.

Comment: Make sure that annotation processing has proper directory configured in `Test sources directory` for your module. And then I've noticed that IntelliJ does not peek up changes on the fly. I had to refresh project. So maybe reopening IDE could help.

Comment: Still didn't work. I've posted an answer on how I got it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. Create a directory in the *Module root* called `generated` and under it have two simlinks to `<ProjectRoot>/out/production/<ProjectModule>/generated/` and `<ProjectRoot>/out/test/<ProjectModule>/generated_tests/`. Mark the first as **Resource Root** and the second as **Test Resource Root**.

I created the new directory and simlinks because it appears Intillij auto-marks `<ProjectRoot>/out` as **Excluded**.

I marked the directory as **Test *Resource* Root** so that Intellij doesn't try to compile the source twice to the same class. (Hint: big complains from the compiler.)

In the end, no red squiggles and auto-complete works.

---

Note: I didn't change the Intellij's generated sources directory for the module. (Well, I did to try another answer, but changed it back.)