# How do you command IntelliJ to create corresponding JUnit tests in a "Tests" directory that mirrors your project structure?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, jetbrains-ide

I moved to JUnit 5 and now IntelliJ only gives me the option to create tests in the same directory as my classes. This is not good. Why this is a readily available option some programmers use eludes me, as choosing such an option would seem to lead to garbled code.

I would like all the tests to be created automatically into a corresponding directory that mirrors my project.

Comment: Check the following link and see if it helps. The ide allows you to mark the directory you want to be identified as the test folder.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/creating-and-managing-modules.html#configuring-content-roots

Comment: @Sid Very helpful link Sid. "Content Roots: Generated Test Sources Root Folders" were the terms I needed to search for in order to solve this problem. However, I think that in my current project, it may be easier to create a new project and copy/paste all the code to the new project that has these folders setup from the beginning. The alternative seems to be deleting and then creating a bunch of folders, then moving tests.

Comment: Yes, you looked at the right section in that link which is to identify the folder you want to use for your tests. As for the part where you feel shorthanded, I think there should be a similar configuration that could be achieved through your build configuration if your current project structure isn't being helpful with the ide, for example in gradle we can configure the directories that is to be used for your tests.

Comment: Hopefully, you are moving in the right direction and if the link helped, I could put it as an answer for you to accept so that it can help others.

Comment: You have moved me in the right direction. Please do put it in the answer section, but I'm going to keep this open for a while since I'm curious to see if others have struggled with this before. I also found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561161/how-to-mark-a-directory-as-a-generated-test-source-root-in-intellij ,which speaks more on generated directories.

Comment: @Sid You definitely pointed me in the right direction, however, since your comment was just a guide to where someone might be able to research how to find the answer, I'm not going to mark it as the accepted answer because the question remains unanswered. However, I did upvote all your answer and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment that helped the OP. Adding it here as an answer as it could help others for various reasons.

Check the following link and see if it helps. The ide allows you to mark the directory you want to be identified as the test folder. [Generated Test Sources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/creating-and-managing-modules.html#configuring-content-roots)